# Memberpress get member from email

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I am creating a plugin in which user purchase a product from **ClickFunnel** and pay through Stripe, Now ClickFunnel does not provide API anymore so I am fetching data from Stripe, After receiving this data I want to do following things:

1. Fetch member from MemberPress based on email
2. Create transaction to update membership

MemberPress provide developer options to get member data, in order to get member I need member id, which i don't have, I only have data received from stripe API.

Data I have received from stripe is:

```
Payment ID: xxxx
Amount: 3700
Products: Test Product
Email: abc@example.com
Name: Mr. ABC
```

I want to fetch members based on email, how can I achieve this via code. client don't want to use third party services like Zapier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this response into your php and want also to get the corresponding WP_User, I assume you could use the `get_user_by()` [method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/#comment-494) like so :

```
<?php $user = get_user_by( 'email', 'user@example.com' );
if ( ! empty( $user ) && ! is_wp_error( $user ) {
    /**
     * User exists
     * @var $user WP_User
     */
     printf( 'User is %s %s.', $user->first_name, $user->last_name );
 }
```